# Can we resize buttons in Adaptive Card?

Tags: node.js, bots, adaptive-cards

Can anyone explain the scenario where we can resize the button in adaptive 
cards. In the adaptivecards.io itself?

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying the editor in adaptivecards.io but dont get a option there to resize the button. I am onle able to do it with CSS properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can resize the button in Adaptive Cards. However, it also depends on where you are trying to display the cards. In Adaptive Cards, hosts like Outlook, Microsoft Teams, and Bot Framework control the size and alignment of buttons. Card authors (people sending cards to these hosts) do not get to control button size and alignment.This is done to ensure that cards rendered on a host always look and feel consistent.

If you're a host, hosting cards in your own website/app, then you can use the host config to control button styles. If you are using Bot Framework SDK, you will have to assign a Host Config in their SDK, as the SDK is rendering the cards. This Host Config would apply to all cards that get rendered within your web page's bot.

[This](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/master/samples/HostConfig/sample.json) is a sample that shows how to integrate host config in the bot solution.

[Attached](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1610) is the GitHub issue related to the same from which the above information is extracted.

Hope this helps!!